# Is there a way to prevent scipy.stats.gamma from producing a jagged pdf for these parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I am running an example similar to the one on the [scipy documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html) for the gamma distribution. I want to plot the pdf of a gamma distribution, but when given the `a = shape = 70368744177664.0` and `scale = 4.073382059442025e-05` I get the jagged plot pictured below:

[image: PDF of gamma distribution]

Checking the x array, it appears to be monotonic, so that is fine:

[image]

looking directly at the probability values (produced by the code below), I see

```
array([6.49723890e-05, 8.34261989e-05, 8.34261989e-05, 8.34261989e-05,
       1.07121360e-04, 1.07121360e-04, 1.37546549e-04, 1.37546549e-04,
       1.37546549e-04, 1.76613264e-04, 1.76613264e-04, 2.26775921e-04,
       2.26775921e-04, 2.26775921e-04, 2.26775921e-04, 2.91186046e-04,
       2.91186046e-04, 3.73890284e-04, 2.91186046e-04, 3.73890284e-04,
       3.73890284e-04, 3.73890284e-04, 4.80084628e-04, 3.73890284e-04,
       4.80084628e-04, 4.80084628e-04, 6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04,
       6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04,
       7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 6.16440864e-04, 7.91525737e-04,
       7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03,
       7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03,
       1.01633916e-03, 7.91525737e-04, 1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03,
       1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03, 7.91525737e-04,
       1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03,
       7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 1.01633916e-03,
       1.01633916e-03, 1.01633916e-03, 7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04,
       7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 7.91525737e-04, 6.16440864e-04,
       6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04, 6.16440864e-04,
       6.16440864e-04, 4.80084628e-04, 4.80084628e-04, 4.80084628e-04,
       4.80084628e-04, 4.80084628e-04, 3.73890284e-04, 3.73890284e-04,
       3.73890284e-04, 3.73890284e-04, 3.73890284e-04, 2.26775921e-04,
       2.26775921e-04, 2.26775921e-04, 2.26775921e-04, 2.26775921e-04,
       2.26775921e-04, 1.76613264e-04, 1.37546549e-04, 1.37546549e-04,
       1.37546549e-04, 1.37546549e-04, 1.37546549e-04, 8.34261989e-05,
       8.34261989e-05, 8.34261989e-05, 8.34261989e-05, 6.49723890e-05])
```

If you look closely, you can see sequences such as **`2.91186046e-04, 3.73890284e-04, 2.91186046e-04`**, where the pdf will bounce oscillate values, as we see on the graph. This tells me that this isn't an error in matplotlib.

You can easily replicate this by running:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shape = 70368744177664.0
scale = 4.073382059442025e-05
x = np.linspace(gamma.ppf(0.01, shape, scale = scale), gamma.ppf(0.99, shape, scale = scale), 100)
plt.plot(x, gamma.pdf(x, shape, scale = scale))
plt.show()
```

Comment: `shape = 70368744177664.0`  I am curious where such an extreme value of the shape parameter of a gamma distribution arises in practice.  Can you say something about where this value comes from?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Fit from values tightly clustered above 2866387308 using this method to fit the parameters: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/minka-gamma.pdf

Fit something like np.array([2866387308] * 1000, dtype = np.float64) + np.random.uniform(1e-8, 1000, 1000)

Comment: OK, but where does the data come from? What is the meaning of the samples to which you are fitting the gamma distribution?  Are you just testing the code with random values, or is your data from real measurements of something?   By the way, at those extreme values, I suspect a gamma distribution will be indistinguishable from a normal distribution.

Comment: Indeed, the gamma may look like a normal distribution at those values, which is one of the reasons I chose it. It is a bit of a corner case in an ML algorithm I'm designing. The values are IBD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_by_descent) values between certain closely related individuals.